# ES6 getter setter with JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

According to this doc

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

You can do something like this

```
var o = {
  set current (str) {
    this.log[this.log.length] = str;
  },
  log: []
}
```

But what if I want the `current` variable to be object and I want to do `setter` on a property of that object?

The below doesn't seem to work

```
var o = {
  set current.myVal (str) {
    this.log[this.log.length] = str;
  },
  log: []
}
```

What is the correct way to do this? I read that you can use `expression` but there is no example.

** UPDATE 1 **

One of the answers below is correct but what if it's `class`?

```
class o {
  set current.myVal (str) {
    this.log[this.log.length] = str;
  }
}
```

I tried below and didn't work

```
class o {
  current: {
    set myVal(str) {
      o.log.push(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `set [current.myVal] (str)` ?

Comment: It would help if you could give an example of the code you would like to be able to write using this object. Not just the proposed object itself, but a test case for the object.

Comment: This is an object initializer, not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea, but theoretically you can return an object with a setter for `o.current`:

```js
var o = {
    get current() {
        var self = this;
        return {
            set myVal(str) {
                self.log[self.log.length] = str;
            }
        }
    },
    log: []
};

o.current.myVal = 1234;
o.current.myVal = 5678;

document.write(o.log)
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for

```
var o = {
  current: {
    set myVal(str) {
      o.log.push(str);
    }
  },
  log: []
};
```

But that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: I edited my question because my real case was actually inside a `class`

Comment: @HP. For a class you have to use a getter like in georg's answer, as you need to reference the instance (`self`) and don't already have a reference (`o`) to it. That said, you probably shouldn't be doing this at all, just make `myVal` a direct member of your class.